# Looking a method to wait/stay other threads while a thread in a void?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, long-polling

I'm looking a method to wait all threads while a thread in a void...

I have normally 10 threads running.

And I have a void, which is important...

All threads entering that void together.
I would like to wait other threads out of void or start of void...

**For example:**

```
    public static void theVoid(int ID)
    {
        //<THREADS WAIT STATION>
        //ACTIONS
        //ACTIONS
        //<ONE THREAD STILL PROCESSING>
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }
```

If one thread finish the operation of void or reach **end of line** of the void other thread will continue.

And same...

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at WaitHandler.WaitAll

Comment: A minus rate giver, surfing, cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would a `lock` work for you?

```
private static object gate = new object();

public static void theVoid(int ID)
{
    lock (gate)
    {
        //<THREADS WAIT STATION>
        //ACTIONS
        //ACTIONS
        //<ONE THREAD STILL PROCESSING>
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }
}
```